# how to insert 5 specific lines when encounter a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'am trying to copy 5 lines (I should maybe try to insert instead of copy) when I find a specific word on a column !

Here is the problem I'am facing... becoming less and less a beginner question after question on Stackoverflow, I have been able to find the word and replace it but only by the first cell of the first column of the 5 lines I wan't to copy...
SO the question is this one :
How can I replace the value I find "KIKOU" by the content of 5 line (A1:Z5) from the other spreadsheet ?

```
function CONCEPTION_001() {
  var GOsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var TRUCsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TRUC");


 var vs = TRUCsheet.getRange(1,1,TRUCsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
 var tableur = GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z5' + GOsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();


   
  var o = vs.map((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] === "KIKOU") {
      return [tableur];//set value 
    } else {
      return [r[0]];//set value
    }

  })
  TRUCsheet.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);

}
```

Comment: Can you log the 'tableur' variable to see what's in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to insert the values of `tableur` to the row that column "A" that has a value of `KIKOU`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z5' + GOsheet.getLastRow())` might be `GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z' + GOsheet.getLastRow())` or `GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z5')`.
- In your situation, how about the following flow?

  1. Retrieve all values from "TRUC" sheet. And, retrieve values of `tableur`.
  2. When column "A" of "TRUC" is `KIKOU`, the values of `tableur` is inserted into the value of "TRUC" sheet.
  3. Clear "TRUC" sheet. And, put the new values on "TRUC" sheet.

I thought that by this flow, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little rather than the use of `insertRows` method. When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function CONCEPTION_001() {
  var GOsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var TRUCsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TRUC");
  
  // I modified the below script.
  var range = TRUCsheet.getRange(1, 1, TRUCsheet.getLastRow(), TRUCsheet.getLastColumn());
  var tableur = GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z' + GOsheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // or GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z5').getValues()
  var o = range.getValues().flatMap(r => r[0] == "KIKOU" ? tableur : [r]);
  var maxLen = Math.max(...o.map(r => r.length));
  var values = o.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  range.clearContent();
  TRUCsheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the above flow is run.
- If you want to insert the values of "A1:Z5" of "GO" sheet, please modify them as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var tableur = GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z' + GOsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var tableur = GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z5').getValues();
    ```
- If you want to keep the row of "KIKOU", please modify `flatMap(r => r[0] == "KIKOU" ? tableur : [r])` to `flatMap(r => r[0] == "KIKOU" ? [r, ...tableur] : [r])`.
- Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, as another approach, if you want to also copy the format, how about the following modification? But, in this case, the process cost will be higher than that of the above script.

  ```js
  function CONCEPTION_001() {
    var GOsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
    var TRUCsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TRUC");
    var range = TRUCsheet.getRange(1, 1, TRUCsheet.getLastRow(), TRUCsheet.getLastColumn());
    var tableur = GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z' + GOsheet.getLastRow());
    var rowLen = tableur.getNumRows();
    range.getValues().reduceRight((_, r, i) => {
      if (r[0] == "KIKOU") {
        var row = i + 1;
        TRUCsheet.deleteRow(row);
        TRUCsheet.insertRows(row, rowLen);
        tableur.copyTo(TRUCsheet.getRange(row, 1));
      }
    });
  }
  ```

  - If you want to keep the row of "KIKOU", please modify as follows.

    - From

      ```
        TRUCsheet.deleteRow(row);
        TRUCsheet.insertRows(row, rowLen);
        tableur.copyTo(TRUCsheet.getRange(row, 1));
      ```
    - To

      ```
        TRUCsheet.insertRows(row + 1, rowLen);
        tableur.copyTo(TRUCsheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));
      ```

#### References:

- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your current issue, I thought that in this case, `forEach` might be useful instead of `reduceRight`. So, please test the following sample script.

```js
function CONCEPTION_001() {
  var GOsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var TRUCsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TRUC");
  var range = TRUCsheet.getRange(1, 1, TRUCsheet.getLastRow(), TRUCsheet.getLastColumn());
  var tableur = GOsheet.getRange('A1:Z' + GOsheet.getLastRow());
  var rowLen = tableur.getNumRows();
  range.getValues().reverse().forEach((r, i, a) => {
    if (r[0] == "KIKOU") {
      var row = a.length - i;
      TRUCsheet.insertRows(row + 1, rowLen);
      tableur.copyTo(TRUCsheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @antho2B From your current situation posted as an answer, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. By the way, please remove your answer. Because that is not your answer.

Comment: @antho2B About `thanks a lot, it's perfectly working know !`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @antho2B About `but is there an easy way to deal with format an value, in a way to print value for ("A1:F5") but format for ("G1:Z5") ? I tried to do something with`, I would like to suppot you. But the question of replying is new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?