# How can I compare 2 list and use the result to insert lines

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I would like to compare the tow list I have created :

"liste01" and "liste02"

if a word from liste02 is not in the liste01
I would like to insert 5 lines by word after the last row of the "CO.sheet"
I have already ask for the 5 lines to insert here :

[insert 5 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76014539/how-to-insert-5-specific-lines-when-encounter-a-specific-value)

here is my code to create the 2 list :

```
function CONCEPTION_004() {
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");
  var COsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1_CONCEPTION 2D/3D");
  

var valuePRO = PROsheet.getRange(2,1,PROsheet.getLastRow() - 1,3).getValues();
 var valueCO = COsheet.getRange(2,1,COsheet.getLastRow() - 1,1).getValues();
 
   
  var listePRO = valuePRO.map((r,i) => {
    var liste01 = r[1];
  Logger.log(liste01)
  })


  var listeCO = valueCO.map((r,i) => {
    var liste02 = r[0];
  

  Logger.log(liste02)
  })



}
```

Comment: Can you please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output? What do you mean by `insert 5 lines by word after the last row`? I understand that you want to compare two lists and if a word from `liste02` is not in `liste01`, you want to add that word in `COsheet`, is that correct? I tested the script from your other post and when a word matches it copies the complete list, it would be great if you include a minimal example that reproduces the issue to test the way you have it and be sure of what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CONCEPTION_004() {
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");
  var COsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1_CONCEPTION 2D/3D");
  var valuePRO = PROsheet.getRange(2, 1, PROsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var valueCO = COsheet.getRange(2, 1, COsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  var listePRO = valuePRO.map((r, i) => {
    let idx = valueCO.indexOf(r[1])
    if(!~idx) {
      //insert your five lines here
    }
  })
}
```